# Call external Postgres database from a NodeJS app deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a nodejs application deployed on AKS Kubernetes that uses the **pg** package to create a connection to a Postgres database

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const config = require('./configuration/config.json');

const client = new Client({
    user: config.postgresDb.user,
    host: config.postgresDb.host,
    database: config.postgresDb.database,
    password: config.postgresDb.password,
    port: config.postgresDb.port
});
```

The connection information is stored in the **config.json** file created using the following ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: server-configmap
data:
  config.json: |
    {
        "postgresDb": {
          "user": "<username>",
          "host": "172.17.0.2",
          "database": "postgres",
          "password": "<password>",
          "port": 5432
        }
    }
```

Locally, the connection between the nodejs app and the Postgres database is working.
Now I want to deploy this on a cloud environment and, in this case, the database is outside the cluster.
How can I use the Kubernetes **Service** and **Endpoint** to call the external database?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found the solution.
I deployed the AKS Kubernetes cluster and the Postgres database on Azure.
If we deploy the Kubernetes cluster and the Postgres database in the same VNet, we don't need **Service** and **Endpoint** to connect a Pod with the database. We need to:

1. Enable the *Service endpoints* in the subnet where we deployed the AKS cluster and,
2. Create a virtual network rule for Postgres.

This is the code.

**Nodejs app**

```
const express = require('express');
const { Client } = require('pg');
const config = require('./configuration/config.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
const port = 3000;

const client = new Client({
    user: config.postgresDb.user,
    host: config.postgresDb.host,
    database: config.postgresDb.database,
    password: config.postgresDb.password,
    port: config.postgresDb.port,   
});

client.connect();

app.get('/cities', (req, res, next) => {

    const cityFilter = req.query.city;
    let query;

    if (cityFilter) {
        query = `SELECT * FROM city 
        WHERE city LIKE '%${cityFilter}%' OR city_ascii LIKE '%${cityFilter}%' OR country LIKE '%${cityFilter}%'
        OR iso2 LIKE '%${cityFilter}%' OR iso3 LIKE '%${cityFilter}%' OR admin_name LIKE '%${cityFilter}%'
        ORDER BY city`;
    }
    else {
        query = 'SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY city'
    }


    client.query(query, (err, dbres) => {
        if (err) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(200).send(dbres.rows);
        }
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**Terraform**

```
# Azure AD admin group: "TEST-AKS-ADMIN"

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  client_id       = ""
  client_secret   = ""
  subscription_id = ""
  tenant_id       = ""
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rgname"
  location = "West Europe"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test_vn" {
  name                = "test-virtual-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks_subnet" {
  name                 = "aks-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test_vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql"] # This enable access to the Postgres Sql
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "dbs_subnet" {
  name                 = "db-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test_vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "test_acr" {
  name                = "TestContainerRegistry"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "test_k8s_cluster" {
  name                = "TetK8s"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "k8stest"

  default_node_pool {
    name                = "systempool"
    node_count          = 1
    vm_size             = "Standard_D2_v2"
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    max_count           = 3
    min_count           = 1
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id

    node_labels = {
      "node-type"   = "system"
      "environment" = "development"
      "nodepoolos"  = "linux"
    }

    tags = {
      "nodepool-type" = "system"
      "environment"   = "development"
      "nodepoolos"    = "linux"
    }

  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = ""
    client_secret = ""
  }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "ubuntu"

    ssh_key {
      key_data = file("./id_rsa.pub")
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    network_plugin    = "azure"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "app_node_pool" {
  enable_auto_scaling   = true
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.test_k8s_cluster.id
  max_count             = 5
  min_count             = 1
  mode                  = "User"
  name                  = "appnodepool"
  os_type               = "Linux" # Default is Linux, we can change to Windows
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  priority              = "Regular" # Default is Regular, we can change to Spot with additional settings like eviction_policy, spot_max_price, node_labels and node_taints
  vnet_subnet_id        = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
  node_labels = {
    "nodepool-type" = "application"
    "environment"   = "development"
    "nodepoolos"    = "linux"
    "technology"    = "nodejs"
  }
  tags = {
    "nodepool-type" = "application"
    "environment"   = "development"
    "nodepools"     = "linux"
    "app"           = "nodejs"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "pg_server" {
  name                = "test-psqlserver"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  administrator_login          = "****"
  administrator_login_password = "****"

  sku_name   = "GP_Gen5_4"
  version    = "11"
  storage_mb = 640000

  backup_retention_days        = 7
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = false
  auto_grow_enabled            = true

  #public_network_access_enabled    = false
  ssl_enforcement_enabled          = true
  ssl_minimal_tls_version_enforced = "TLS1_2"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "app1_database" {
  name                = "app1-db"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  server_name         = azurerm_postgresql_server.pg_server.name
  charset             = "UTF8"
  collation           = "English_United States.1252"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_virtual_network_rule" "app1_db_vnet" {
  name                                 = "postgresql-vnet-rule"
  resource_group_name                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  server_name                          = azurerm_postgresql_server.pg_server.name
  subnet_id                            = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
  ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = false
}
```

**NodeJs deployment & Service**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server1
  labels:
    app: server1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      stack: node
      app: cities-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        stack: node
        app: cities-server
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: volumemap
          configMap:
            name: server1-configmap
      containers:
        - name: cities-server
          image: <image_mame>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: "128M"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volumemap
              mountPath: /user/src/app/configuration

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server1-services
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    tier: backend
    stack: node
    app: cities-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**ConfigMap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: server1-configmap
data:
  config.json: |
    {
        "postgresDb": {
          "user": "db_user",
          "host": "postgres_host",
          "database": "db_name",
          "password": "user_password",
          "port": 5432
        }
    }
```